# How to remove domains starting or end or both with single hyphen?

Tags: domain

How to remove invalid domains, starting or end, or both, with single hyphen?

Example domains to delete:

```
.-domain--.com
.-domain-.com
.domain-.com
.--domain.com
.subdomain.-domain.com
```

failed attempts:

```
grep -vP '-\.'
sed 's/^\.-//'
```

I apologize to those who have already commented. I had to rephrase the question, because it was incorrect. Thank you

Comment: Your output has double hyphens, isn't that what you want to replace?

Comment: My output contains a valid TLD example.xn .-- * therefore that line cannot be deleted, except if the domain has -- example--foo.xn--*. In this one almost eliminated

Comment: why are double hyphens "forbidden"? by who? anyways, `grep -Pv '(?<!xn)--' file` with GNU grep

Comment: `grep -Pv '(^|\.)-|-($|\.)'` or `grep -Pv '^-|-$|\.-|-\.'` or the same with `-Ev` instead of `-Pv`.

Comment: @mosvy Please post the answer to select it as correct. THK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the:

```
grep -Ev '(^|\.)-|-($|\.)'
grep -Ev '^-|-$|\.-|-\.'
```

or, with GNU grep:

```
grep -Pv '(^|\.)-|-($|\.)'
grep -Pv '^-|-$|\.-|-\.'
```